# Error Parsing from CSV file

Tags: java, csv, filereader

I have a CSV file with 90 columns and I try to parse it with `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord`.

I get the first 3 columns perfectly, but when I want to get the 49th column's content it returns the error 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index for header 'column49' is 48 but CSVRecord only has 43 values!`

One part of my code is:

```
protected List<T> readData(Reader reader) throws Exception{
        List<T> items= new ArrayList<T>();
        try{
            Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.APPLE.withDelimiter('|').withHeader(factory.header()).withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(reader);
            for(CSVRecord record : records){
                patients.add(factory.instance(record));
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        return items;
```

I have searched this issue on the internet but the solutions are not works. Is anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can we see a few sample rows of the CSV file?

Comment: Your CSV file seems to be terse, ie records may end prematurely if all remaining values are `null`. This can be checked for each record with the `isConsistent` method. Neither do I know of nor have I found in the docs a way to parse these reliably out-of-the-box

Comment: The `isConsistent` is helpful, thanks